# use MAPIProperties to get Email, how can I convert Ex address to regular address

Tags: c#, outlook, pst

I'm trying to read .pst file that export from outlook.
I use this https://github.com/tghanem/PST library to read emails in pst file.
here is some code:

```
//Arrange
        var sut = GetFolderSut();

        //Act
        var result = sut.GetMessages()[0].GetProperty(MAPIProperties.PidTagSenderEmailAddress);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("user1@test.lab", result.Value.Value.ToUnicode());
```

when I try to get SenderEmailAddress, I got something like Ex address: /O=DOMAINNAME/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHI43SPCLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=JOE BLOGGS8C3
but I want it to be a regular email address such as test@gmail.com. How can I do that?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

While using the Outlook object model you can use the [ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2098);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to get a string representing the primary Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the `ExchangeUser`.

```
/// <summary> 
/// Finds the SMTP addres based on an exchange string inside an outlook contact 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="">Has to be an exchange address string</param> 
/// <returns></returns> 
private string GetSMTPAddressViaOutlookObjectModel(string exchangeAddress) 
{ 
    // Start with an empty string 
    var address = string.Empty; 
 
    // Create a recipients with the exchange address 
    // E.g. ..... 
    Outlook.Recipient recipient = Module.OutlookApp.Session.CreateRecipient(exchangeAddress); 
 
    // Resolve the recipient 
    recipient.Resolve(); 
 
    // When the recipient is resolved 
    if (recipient.Resolved) 
    { 
        // Get the user behind the resolved address 
        Outlook.ExchangeUser user = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser(); 
 
        // If the user is found 
        if (user != null) 
        { 
            // set the address to the primary SMTP address of the exchange user 
            address = user.PrimarySmtpAddress; 
            // Release the user object 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(user); 
        } 
 
        // Release the recipient object 
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipient); 
    } 
 
    // return the address 
    return address; 
}
```

Another way is to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - to get other address types, we need to find the recipient in the Outlook address book by using the [IAddrBook.ResolveName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iaddrbook-resolvename) method, then reach the `IMailUser` interface with the [IAddrBook.OpenEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iaddrbook-openentry) method and get the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` property. Read more about that in the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article.